# How to prevent "SHOW CREATE TABLE" while code changes in python flask app in development?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, reload

I am working on a Flask application, in which whenever any code changes the server has been restarted to reflect new changes in development mode. Which is correct, but it is also reloaded or check the tables in the database.

I am using sqlalchemy ORM. Whenever I save any code changes it is always reload or check the tables. Please find below the logs:

```
2020-11-10 12:34:28,144 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,145 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2020-11-10 12:34:28,146 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,146 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2020-11-10 12:34:28,147 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,147 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2020-11-10 12:34:28,148 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,148 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2020-11-10 12:34:28,153 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,153 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2020-11-10 12:34:28,154 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,154 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2020-11-10 12:34:28,156 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,156 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2020-11-10 12:34:28,158 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,158 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2020-11-10 12:34:28,159 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,159 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2020-11-10 12:34:28,160 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
2020-11-10 12:34:28,160 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
```

I need to prevent this behavior. How can I do this, please help me.